# IE changes the size of my background image

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have a DIV with a background image (a big one, like 2000px height). In Internet Explorer 8, this background image gets resized and becomes smaller, so that it loops (even if I said "no-repeat" !). What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: No reason it should happen, but could you show the entirety of the CSS for that div?

Comment: Are you able to place it in http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce please?

Comment: Attaches the code might helps. A simple html might explains.

Comment: Is that ok if I provided the URL : it's http://dtssbcnyc.blogspot.com/ The DIV is the right sidebar, can you see the social icons at the bottom of this sidebar? In IE the background image is (1) reduced in size (2) looped. The original size of this background image is FAR bigger than this DIV you see. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Try using chrome or other browser to inspect element, you can check what elsestylesare applied to the div.